# Show content from external php file with GET parameter inside div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Im struggling to make links for files appear on same page inside DIV.
Simply nothing happens when I a href click link, no links appear.. however I can see links when I'm going directly to example.com/ajaxdetails.php?id=OneOftheIDs
Here is mine main HTML file:

```
<script src="/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
function getSummary(id)
{
   $.ajax({

     type: "GET",
     url: "detailsajax.php",
     data: "id=" + id,
     success: function(data) {
          $('#returned-details').html(data);
     }

   });

}
</script>
```

PHP part:

```
foreach ($pirmiRezai as $key=>$rezultatas)
    { $i++;
    echo '<div class="r">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="getSummary('.$rezultatas['ID'].')">'.$rezultatas['desc'].'</a>
    Some unrelated php code here
    <div id="returned-details"></div>
    </div>';
    if($i>=10)
    break;
    }
```

And the detailsajax.php file contains simple textarea with returned download link from database for specific ID (detailsajax.php?id=random). I need that html code with returned download link to appear inside returned-details DIV next to a href that was clicked.
Hope its clear.

Comment: So do you have an issue? What is not working? What is it doing compared to what you want it to do?

Comment: personally i feel this is a bit messy, if i was you, i will only return $rezultatas as json then use the result to do all content formatting at client side.

Comment: looks like you will have more than one div with the same id - which will be a problem. add `$rezultatas['ID']` to make a unique div id and change the ajax function to address it

Comment: Now when I click A href... nothing happens.. nothing appears inside returned-details div. But when im opening detailsajax.php?id=neededID I can see page is not empty and download link is there. Dagon, as I understand I need to add id="neededUniqueID".. but alax part is tricky for me. im completely new with it. How could I make it to address unique id of div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `id's` should be always unique or else u could replace it with the `class` attribute.In your case something like this might help u mate.. :)

**Script**

```
    <script src="/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".r a").on("click", function() {
            var id = $(this).attr("myId");
            $.ajax({

                type: "GET",
                url: "detailsajax.php",
                data: "id=" + id,
                context: this,
                success: function(data) {
                    $(this).next('.returned-details').html(data);
                }

            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
foreach ($pirmiRezai as $key=>$rezultatas)
    { $i++;
    echo '<div class="r">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" myId="'.$rezultatas['ID'].'">'.$rezultatas['desc'].'</a>
    Some unrelated php code here
    <div class="returned-details"></div>
    </div>';
    if($i>=10)
    break;
    }
```

Comment: Seems like you pointing me to right direction mate, however after I made you suggested changes.. still nothing happens when I click a href link with myId.. :S I've also tried changing  $(".r a").on("click", function() to  $(".linkas a").on("click", function() and renaming Div class in which a href is to linkas.. still nothing happens

Comment: try putting an alert inside the click function and also check if there are any console errros..

Comment: Could you be more specific with alert? (Im total newbie with Javascript stuff :D) 
P.S. Console shows absolutely nothing... Neither on load nor on a href click.

Comment: try adding a alert('123') after `$(".r a").on("click", function() {` .check if it detects the click

Comment: debug inside the ajax success function

Comment: added: alert('click works'); into success function.. strangely also works fine.. got message as intended...

Comment: Replace `$(this).next('.returned-details').html(data);` with `$(this).parent().find('.returned-details').html(data);`